# Test XSL for missing element

Tags: xml, xslt

I know that questions similar to this have been asked but I can't work out what is wrong with my test.

Here are 3 variations of how my XML could be like;
I am trying to work out the presence of a value for `<apsite:address>`, an empty string or a missing element.

```
 <apsite:apsite xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <apsite:name>John</apsite:name>
  <apsite:address>Some Address</apsite:name>
 </apsite:apsite>

<apsite:apsite xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <apsite:name>John</apsite:name>
  <apsite:address></apsite:name>
 </apsite:apsite>

<apsite:apsite xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <apsite:name>John</apsite:name>
</apsite:apsite>
```

I need to find the instances where the value of  is an empty string or null.
These are my if conditions.

```
                              <xsl:if  
                test="../apsite:address = ''">
                <dc:source>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </dc:source>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if
                test="not(apsite:apsite/apsite:address)">
                <dc:source>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </dc:source>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if
                test="../apsite:adress != ''">
                <dc:source>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../apsite:oldAddress" />
                </dc:source>
            </xsl:if>
```

My test for the empty string works but not for the missing element i.e test="not(apsite:apsite/apsite:address)"> is not working.

Could someone please advise what I am missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean missing `element`, not missing `attribute`. Your sample input documents do not have any attributes. `<apsite:address/>` is an XML **element**.

Comment: Try `test="not(../apsite:address)"` instead of `test="not(apsite:apsite/apsite:address)"`. You might also like to consider using templates rather than an ugly chain of xsl:if instructions.

Comment: Thanks @SeanB.Durkin I have changed the reference from attribute to element. Tried not(../apsite:address) with the same negative result.

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using? 1.0? or 2.0?

Comment: I'm using Version 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet ...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:apsite="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524099" 
  xmlns:dc="some-other-url" >
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="apsite:address[.='']">
  <dc:source>
    <xsl:value-of select="'New value'" />
  </dc:source>
  <xsl:comment>&apos;address&apos; element was empty.</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="apsite:address[not(.='')]">
  <dc:source>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </dc:source>
  <xsl:comment>Text of &apos;address&apos; element was copied.</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="apsite:apsite[not(apsite:address)]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <dc:source>
      <xsl:value-of select="'New value'" />
    </dc:source>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:comment>&apos;address&apos; element was absent.</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...when applied in turn to each of these 3 possible input documents...**

Test case 1: Input document:

```
<apsite:apsite xmlns:apsite="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524099">
  <apsite:name>John</apsite:name>
  <apsite:address>Some Address</apsite:address>
</apsite:apsite>
```

Test case 2: Input document:

```
<apsite:apsite xmlns:apsite="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524099">
  <apsite:name>John</apsite:name>
  <apsite:address></apsite:address>
</apsite:apsite>
```

Test case 3: Input document:

```
<apsite:apsite xmlns:apsite="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524099">
  <apsite:name>John</apsite:name>
</apsite:apsite>
```

**...yields respectively...**

Test Case 1 output:

```
<apsite:apsite xmlns:apsite="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524099">
  <apsite:name>John</apsite:name>
  <dc:source xmlns:dc="some-other-url">Some Address</dc:source>
  <!--Text of 'address' element was copied.-->
</apsite:apsite>
```

Test Case 2 output:

```
<apsite:apsite xmlns:apsite="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524099">
  <apsite:name>John</apsite:name>
  <dc:source xmlns:dc="some-other-url">New value</dc:source>
  <!--'address' element was empty.-->
</apsite:apsite>
```

Test Case 3 output:

```
<apsite:apsite xmlns:apsite="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524099">
  <apsite:name>John</apsite:name>
  <dc:source xmlns:dc="some-other-url">New value</dc:source>
</apsite:apsite>
<!--'address' element was absent.-->
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Sean. I had some issues with my data and the XML test was actually working fine. Thanks for all your help.